# How to include bin/java via Java fx:deploy on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, ant, javafx

I'm trying to get JavaFX Ant  to package up my (Swing) code with the JRE for Mac OS X.
I've got almost everything working, but I can't figure out how to include jre/bin/java.  It looks like all the other relevant stuff from jre/ is included (e.g. all the jre/lib/).
Here's my ant task:

```
<fx:deploy outdir="${appdir}" outfile="${appname}" nativeBundles="image">
    <fx:info title="${appname}" vendor="${vendor}"/>
    <fx:application name="${appname}"/>
    <fx:bundleArgument arg="icon" value="${appname}.icns"/>
    <fx:resources>
        <fx:fileset dir=".">
            <include name="${objar}"/>
        </fx:fileset>
    </fx:resources>
    <fx:platform basedir="${jdk-base}"/>
</fx:deploy>
```

Is there a way to get  to include jre/bin/java?  Or should it already be doing this and so I should look for something screwed up on my system?
Is there a way to add stuff via scripting (e.g. like the "package/macosx/post-image.sh" mechanism)?
Is the ant-javafx source available somewhere?
Any other suggestions?
thx.

Comment: Update: I found some info: The ant task seems to be com.sun.javafx.tools.ant.DeployFXTask.  I got some source code via grepcode.

Comment: See: [Native Packaging Cookbook: Drop in resources](https://blogs.oracle.com/talkingjavadeployment/entry/native_packaging_cookbook_using_drop)

Comment: Thanks, but the "post-image.sh" script doesn't help because it runs after codesign and so breaks it.  (Also, it doesn't run for nativeBundles="image" for some reason - only for "dmg" and "all".)

Comment: It seem broken to me, at least on 1.8.0_40.  I guess I'll work on an alternative solution.